# Python Convert String to Float without Scientific Notation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code to convert string to float:

```
n = float('9400108205499941468492')
```

My unittest throws exceptions:

```
self.assertEqual(9400108205499941468492, n)

Expected :9400108205499941468492
Actual   :9.400108205499941e+21
```

What should I do to disable scientific notation in float().

Comment: These are equivalent. The way it is displayed is irrelevant. The unit test is failing because you are comparing an int to a float.

Comment: The problem isn't the scientific notation. The problem is that floats don't have enough precision to represent that number.

Answer (score 1):

As Josh Friedlander mentions you are comparing an int to a float which will always be invalid.

In order to represent a float without scientific notation you can use Decimal but this is also not going to make your comparison to an int valid...

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> n = float('9400108205499941468492')
>>> format(Decimal.from_float(n))
'9400108205499941388288'
>>> y = format(Decimal.from_float(n))
>>> type(y)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use int() instead of float and when you add 0.5 or any other float then if you want the approximate value then you use int

Comment: i believe 9400108205499941468492 is too big for int.

Comment: @topcan5 - Nope
    >>> x = 9400108205499941468492

    >>> x

    9400108205499941468492

    >>> type(x)

    <class 'int'>